# What is diameter and growth of group generated by two cyclic permutations having only two common elements (rotation group of two-circle puzzle)?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, rubiks-cube

Consider subgroup of S_n generated by two cyclic permutations of the form  described below. (Roughly speaking cycles having only two common elements).

Question: what is known about its growth and diameter ?

Growth seems to be about 2.7 - see computational experiments here: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/464953

Remark: Grwoth and diameter are quite related - since probably one can estimate number of elements combinatorily and afterwards diameter can be estimated as about: log_growth(group-size).

The group is described like that. Let us give the examples first. It is generated by by two cyclic permutations denoted "l" and "r".

```
n = 10
l (0 1 2 3 4 5)
r (0 6 7 2 8 9)

n = 12
l (0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
r (0 7 8 9 2 10 11)

n = 22
l (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
r (0 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 3 19 20 21)

n = 40
l (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20)
r (0 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 6 34 35 36 37 38 39)
```

I.e. first is cycling moving 0...k, second is k+1...n with two intersecting positions.

That group can be thought as symmetry group of the puzzle consisting of two circles:
[image]
https://www.kaggle.com/code/marksix/visualize-allowed-moves

Or the similar subgroup appears when we make rotation of the Rubik's cube around two facets:
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2Fimq4s00bgx1a1.gif%3Fformat%3Dmp4%26s%3Dabea9b805f838832ba835c36eeefd2e73fd2eae1

Comment: It is not surprising that the growth factor is close to 3. You have two generators and their inverses, so four available moves, but since you don't want to undo the previous move you only have 3 choices for every move after the first. I've written up a bit about the relation between growth and the presence of identities on my page about [Cayley graphs](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cayley.htm) which you may like. In general I don't think the behaviour can be precisely calculated other than fully generating the group elements.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks for sharing !

Comment: @DerekHolt computated for Rubik cube some years ago - getting 13 :
https://mathoverflow.net/a/322879/10446

Comment: We probably need Derek Holt (or somebody with similar expertise on pemutation groups) to say something general. Unless the 2 intersecting positions are carelessly chosen, you seem to get at least a doubly transitive group. By *careless* I mean choices like $n=10$, $\alpha_1=(012345)$, $\alpha_2=(067389)$, when we see that the action is imprimitive, as both cycles respect the partition into the blocks $\{0,3\}$, $\{1,4\}$, $\{2,5\}$, $\{6,8\}$, $\{7,9\}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot ! Glad to hear from you !!!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sure that if the distance between the intersections points on one of the rings is coprime to the size of that same ring, then the generated group will be the symmetric or alternating group. Not so sure however when neither ring has that property. The example you give is very much like the [Equator puzzle](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/equator.htm). I analysed groups arising from overlapping cycles [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/graphpuzz.htm) but I excluded cycles with more than one overlap and never went on to analyse them further.

Comment: Unless I made a mistake (possible), I managed to show that in your $n=10$ example you get the full symmetric group. Commutators are a great way to build permutations with small support (I use it on [my ancient Rubik's cube page](https://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/RubikAnim.html)). If the cycles intersected at a single point, you would automatically get 3-cycles. This time the commutator of $\ell$ and $r^3$ gives type $(2,2)$, like $(02)(15)$. Using that and $\ell$, lead to a 3-cycle and from that point on it becomes easier. @Jaap probably has more experience, and may be able to say more.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis would you be so kind to look on Jyrki's comment above

Comment: trivial remak - for even length of cycles it should NOT be A_n, because the determinant will give a  non-trivial character to {-1,1} which is impossible for A_n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some explorations of the groups generated by these intersecting cycles. It is a work in progress and not a complete answer.

Let $L$ and $R$ be the following cycle permutations:
$$L = (l_0, l_1, ..., l_m, ..., l_{M-1}) \\
R = (r_0, r_1, ..., r_n, ..., r_{N-1})$$
They share exactly two elements $l_0=r_0$ and $l_m=r_n$. So $L$ is a cycle of length $M$, in which the shared elements are a distance of $m$ apart, and $R$ is of length $N$ where the shared elements are $n$ apart.
We may assume wlog that $m<=M/2$ and $n<=N/2$.

The question is about the diameter of the group as generated by these two cycles and their inverses.

If you think of this as a permutation puzzle, then there are $4$ possible moves (two faces that can be turned in either direction) and you want to know how many moves it takes to solve in the worst case. From the solved state you can do any of the $4$ moves to reach a different state. After that, one of the four moves would undo the previous one while the other three possible moves could create a new state. So after $k$ moves, at most $p_k=1+4+4\cdot3^1+4\cdot3^2+...+4\cdot3^{k-1}$ distinct states can be reached. If you know the size of the group then you can get a lower bound for the diameter by looking at when $p_k$ first exceeds the group size.

Let's try to find the size of the generated group. It should be noted that this has been analysed before by [David Singmaster](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/cubic5.htm#p9), but it is always good to replicate results. My results below match his, except that I found another special edge case (with $M=2$) that it seems he did not consider.

Let $S$ be the commutator $S=L^m R^n L^{-m} R^{-n}$.
If $m<M/2$ and $n<N/2$ (strict inequalities), then $S$ is merely a double swap $(l_0,l_m)(l_{2m},r_{2n})$.

We can conjugate $S$ by $L$ to get $S'= L S L^{-1}$ which will generally be the double swap $(l_1,l_{m+1})(l_{2m+1},r_{2n})$. For this to work we need $2m+1<M$ and $m>1$.

We can now let T be the permutation $T=(S S')^2$ which is the very useful 3-cycle $(l_{2m},l_{2m+1},r_{2n})$. This has only one element in common with the $R$ cycle, so it is easy to commute with $R^k$ to generate all even permutations of the $r_i$, and from there all even permutations of all $N+M-2$ elements. (For proof see for example the extension lemma on my page on [rotational puzzles on graphs](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/graphpuzz.htm).)
We therefore get at least the alternating group $A_{N+M-2}$. If $N$ and $M$ are both odd, then $L$ and $R$ are both even permutations and we get only the alternating group. If one or both $N$ and $M$ is even, then we must get odd permutations as well and hence the full symmetric group $S_{N+M-2}$.

If $2m+1=M$ and $M>6$ then we can use $S'= L^2 S L^{-2}$ instead, and the same argument works and again we get the alternating or symmetric group. Similarly, if $m=1$ and $M\ge6$ then $S'= L^3 S L^{-3}$ works.

The puzzle is symmetric, so we can swap the roles of $L$ and $R$. This means that the remaining cases will have $(M,m)$ and $(N,n)$ equal to $(3,1)$, $(4,1)$, $(5,1)$, or $(5,2)$. Note that if $(M,m)=(5,2)$ then we can use $L^2$ as a generator instead of $L$, because $(L^2)^3=L^5=L$. This makes it equivalent to having $(M,m)=(5,1)$ instead. Therefore all these cases have $m=n=1$, and fall under the puzzles analysed in [rotational puzzles on graphs](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/graphpuzz.htm). The only exceptional case is $M=N=4$, $m=n=1$, which has a group isomorphic to $S_5$ rather than the expected $S_6$. See also [this page](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/pgl25.htm) for more.

So in almost all the cases so far, the size of the group is $\frac{(M+N-2)!}2$ when M and N are both odd, and $(M+N-2)!$ otherwise.

What is left now is to see what happens when $m=M/2$ and/or $n=N/2$.

**Case 1:** $M=2m$, and $\gcd(n,N)=1$
In this case $R^n$ is still an $N$-cycle, and $L$ swaps two adjacent elements in that cycle, making it equivalent to having $n=1$. It is easy to prove that all even permutations are possible.

**Case 2:** $M=2m$, and $N=2n$
The elements form antipodal pairs which never separate. The puzzle can be interpreted as having m+n-1 pieces, each of which has two possible orientations. An example of a physical puzzle of this sort is the [Equator](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/equator.htm). All even permutations
of these pairs is possible, and if $N$ or $M$ is divisible by $4$ then odd permutations too. Any two of these pairs can be flipped in place, and if $N$ or $M$ is not divisible by $4$ then any single pair can be flipped. So

- if $M\equiv N\equiv0 \pmod 4$ then the group is of order $(m+n-1)!\cdot 2^{m+n-2}$
- if $M\equiv N\equiv2 \pmod 4$ then the group is of order $\frac{(m+n-1)!}2\cdot 2^{m+n-1}$
- if $M\not\equiv N \pmod 4$ then the group is of order $(m+n-1)!\cdot 2^{m+n-1}$

**Case 3:** $M=2m$, and $\gcd(n,N)=d>2$
If $m=1$ then the pieces form $d$ orbits. In each orbit, all permutations are possible, so the group is $(S_{N/d})^d$ and has order $(N/d)!^d$.
If $m>1$, then those orbits from the $m=1$ case merge, and the usual alternating or symmetric group appears depending on the parities of $N$ and $M$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Here is some analysis by colleague : The order of the group of puzzle wreath_6/6 is 3628800

The order of the group of puzzle wreath_7/7 is 239500800

The order of the group of puzzle wreath_12/12 is 1124000727777607680000  https://www.kaggle.com/code/snopoff/group-theory-of-santa-puzzles?scriptVersionId=158483910&cellId=8  may be of some help

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Those results are as expected, being $|S_{10}|$,  $|A_{12}|$,  and $|S_{22}|$ respectively. I think I have finished finished checking all the cases now, so the group size is now known for each.

Comment: Sharing that answer on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/467771

Comment: Dear Jaap would you be so kind to take a look on another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4848434/21498