# Information on permutation subgroups - symmetries of "Globe" like puzzle.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, recreational-mathematics

Consider series of subgroups denoted "Globe A/B" (A,B - integer positive parameters of group) of permutations group $S_{2(A+1)B}$, which are defined below.
They are somewhat similar to symmetries groups of "Globes" Rubik's puzzle, but not exactly these groups.

**Question:** I wonder about any information about such groups - may be there are isomorphic  to some well-known groups ?  (Like happened e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4842187/21498)). Or discussed in some literature ? Or one can propose some structural information ?

Remark. Orders of the some examples of these groups  given [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/469439).

Context: these groups appeared in the interesting ongoing [data-science challenge on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/overview), where participants are competing to find  shorter paths between given elements on Cayley graphs of these groups. Interaction between Kaggle and Math communities can be quite fruitful , imho.

Let us start with example: "Globe 3/4" - 4=3+1 generators $r_i$, and 8 generators $f_i$:
['r0', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7']

```
r0 (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
r1 (8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15)
r2 (16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23)
r3 (24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31)
f0 (0 27)(1 26)(2 25)(3 24)(8 19)(9 18)(10 17)(11 16)
f1 (1 28)(2 27)(3 26)(4 25)(9 20)(10 19)(11 18)(12 17)
f2 (2 29)(3 28)(4 27)(5 26)(10 21)(11 20)(12 19)(13 18)
f3 (3 30)(4 29)(5 28)(6 27)(11 22)(12 21)(13 20)(14 19)
f4 (4 31)(5 30)(6 29)(7 28)(12 23)(13 22)(14 21)(15 20)
f5 (0 29)(5 24)(6 31)(7 30)(8 21)(13 16)(14 23)(15 22)
f6 (0 31)(1 30)(6 25)(7 24)(8 23)(9 22)(14 17)(15 16)
f7 (0 25)(1 24)(2 31)(7 26)(8 17)(9 16)(10 23)(15 18)
```

More examples listed here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexandervc/santa23-eda?scriptVersionId=158030054&cellId=28

So - the general pattern - there $A+1$ cyclic commuting generators $r_i$ and $2*B$ generators of order 2 - $f_i$ which are products of commuting transpositions.
The pictorial descriptions of the generators which specifies the detailed definition,
can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/code/marksix/visualize-allowed-moves?scriptVersionId=157617610&cellId=43

I.e. numbers 1..n rearranged into rectangle of $A+1,2B$, generators $r_i$ make cyclic rotations in horizontal directions, while $f_i$ are flipping vertically halves of rectangle.

Let me quote one example for "Globe 2/6":
[image]

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/q/462618/10446 and
https://www.kaggle.com/code/snopoff/structural-analysis-of-globe-groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the generalized [masterball](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/master.htm) puzzle.

Consider the following move sequence (using left to right notation):

$$f_1 r_1 f_1 r_1^{-1}\ \ r_2 f_1 r_2^{-1} f_1$$
Call this move sequence $D$. It looks like this:

[image: Masterball double swap]

This is the permutation $(8\ 9)(16\ 17)$, so it does a transposition in two of the layers.
If you now take $(D\ r_1)^7$, where the exponent is one less than the number of pieces in the layer, you get the permutation $(16\ 17)$, a clean transposition. It does not take much to show that conjugations of this transposition allow you to achieve every permutation of the two layers $r_1,r_2$.

This generalizes to any size ball, and to any pair of opposite layers. For odd $A$, you have $n=\frac{A+1}2$ pairs of layers, and each pair of layers has $4B$ pieces that can be permuted in every way. This gives the group $(S_{4B})^n$, which has size $(4B)!^n$.

For even $A$ there is a middle layer. It seems that in this case the definition of the flips $f_i$ is such that they do not affect this layer. Therefore the permutation group of the pieces in the middle layer is simply $<r_{A/2}>$ which is a cyclic group of order $2B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do not you want to participate in that challenge or just share your exprience - make some post and/or webinar ?

Comment: Here is question on "diameter" estimation - if would have  time to look - would be great https://mathoverflow.net/q/462618/10446

Comment: An analogy of the puzzle and encryption machine: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/470799#2620179

Comment: I've made some calculations of the orders of the groups obtained by such permutations. In the case of odd $A$ the results of the experiments coincide with your observations. However in the case of even $A$ the results don't match: my results show much bigger numbers. Partial results on the calculations are listed [here](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/santa-2023/discussion/469439)

Comment: A little update: I've checked my findings, you are totally right. The total answer is indeed the following: if $A$ is odd, then $Globe_{/}\simeq (_{4B})^{\frac{+1}{2}}$, and otherwise $Globe_{/}\simeq (_{4B})^{\frac{}{2}} \times C_{2B}$, where $C_n$ is a cyclic group of order